# Shopware 6.4 Cache tag "translator.error.VIOLATION::IS_BLANK_ERROR" contains reserved characters "{}()/\@:" Error

Tags: symfony, caching, shopware, shopware6, symfony5

I want to create a register and login modal popup on the product details page on Shopware 6.4. When I include the login.html.twig template, everything works fine, but when I include the register.html.twig template, I get the error:

`Cache tag translator.error.VIOLATION::IS_BLANK_ERROR" contains reserved characters "{}()/\@:`

How do I eliminate or at least suppress the error?

`{% block modal_test %} {% sw_include '@Storefront/storefront/component/account/register.html.twig' %} {% endblock %}`

[image]

Comment: what exact version of shopware? it looks like maybe it was fixed in 6.4.19 https://forum.shopware.com/t/contains-reserved-characters/90228/7